# Styled radio buttons in a dynamic list

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I would like to use radio buttons, styled to look like normal buttons, within cards that are dynamically generated within a loop.

For example:

```
<?php
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    echo '<div class="card">';
    echo '<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">';
    echo '<label class="btn btn-success btn-rounded">';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="option" id="' . $i . '" />Select';
    echo '</label>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
?>
```

I'd hoped this would mean only one radio button could be selected but it's not the case. I tried moving the btn-group outside the loop like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<?php
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    echo '<div class="card">';
    echo '<label class="btn btn-success btn-rounded">';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="option" id="' . $i . '" />Select';
    echo '</label>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
?>
</div>
```

but that didn't have the right result, as it exposed the actual radio button which is supposed to look like a normal button, and also broke all the styling of the cards.

Is there something obvious that I've missed?

Comment: `$ii` is a syntax error, the 2nd `i` is treated as a constant; remove it.

Comment: the value of `$max` is unknown.

Comment: voting this as a typographical error

Comment: If you want the cards to behave like radio buttons, you should look for how to override the style of a `<input type="radio">` and then style it like a card. Use the bootstrap classes with care since they add not just style to elements but also their own "radio button" behavior.

Comment: Indeed, should be $i++ (just a typo on this request, not in the actual code)

Comment: Hoped it would be clear that $max was defined elsewhere, I didn't want to put in more code than was necessary.

Comment: Question and code is clear, they broadly comply with the "How to ask questions" guidelines. Typo and omitting `$max` is okay.

Comment: Thank you. In the end I think I resolved the issue. I essentially did what's in the second code box above, but without the class="btn-group" and it seems to work. Not yet tested across multiple browsers though.